# Find out what build target is currently running after electron-builder

Tags: windows, electron, electron-builder, appx

I am currently packaging my electron app using electron-builder and I want to add AppX as a target to publish the app to the Microsoft Store.

The problem is that I normally use electron-updater to update the application and show a button in the UI to check for updates. I now want to disable this behaviour when building to the AppX target as the Microsoft Store is handling this for me then.

Is there some sort of method to check what building target I am currently running?

Something like (just pseudocode - clearly doesn't work):

```
import electron from 'electron';

if (electron.target !== 'appx') {
  ...
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Found the answer: You can use `electron`'s "process.windowsstore" variable:

https://www.electronjs.org/docs/api/process#processwindowsstore-readonly

Comment: Same goes for Mac App Store (`process.mas`). Nice!